# Is it possible to create an Excel spreadsheet where each cell is an image?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically the title: I wanted to create an Excel spreadsheet where each one of the entries contains an image, so that when you click it the image expands. Kinda of making the image work like an hyperlink to an expanded version of the image.

Comment: What' the meaning of "when you click it the image expands">?

Comment: I want to put an image in each cell scaled to cell size to make visualization easier, but if you select the cell's content you automatically see the image in it's full size, without having to manually rescale it. Don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Although it probably could be done by using VBA, it seems a photo or file manager would be more suitable for your task.